# How can I access a RESTful API in PHP that is password projected (I know the password)

Tags: php, rest

So for example here is a URL: https://rexms.net:32005/rexwapi/common/timeframes -- if I go to that URL in my browser enter the correct username/password it will spit out XML at me.  The problem is I need to access this through PHP so I obviously don't get a prompt to enter username/password.

Current code is:

```
$timeframes_xml = simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents('https://rexms.net:32005/rexwapi/common/timeframes'));
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can simply use

```
https://username:password@rexms.net:32005/rexwapi/common/timeframes
```

Comment: This seems inconsistent.  I did it in PHP and it didn't return results, same when I tried in MSIE buuuut when I tried in Google Chrome it DID work, any ideas on what may be causing that?

Comment: IE disabled this as it's implementation had security flaws. PHP parses the data and sets it as required :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to set the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option.

Comment: I've tried doing this a few ways and can't seem to get results, is there anyone you could write a code sample?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Http header Authorization.  Set the value to a base64 encoded version of

```
Basic username:password
```

That is assuming the server is using basic auth.  On Windows you could use Fiddler to see what type of auth the server is requesting.

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to approach this using three PEAR packages: HTTP/Socket/Net. With the HTTP package you are able to make REST requests to a Basic Auth realm easily.

For more check out: [How To: Making a PHP REST client to call REST resources](http://www.sematopia.com/?p=153)

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer [in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783205/hiding-responses-using-php-and-curl)

```
function get_rex_xml($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'username:password'));
    ob_start();
    $response_xml = curl_exec($curl);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response_xml;
}

header('content-type:text/xml');
echo get_rex_xml('https://rexms.net:32005/rexwapi/common/timeframes');
```